# Is Ukraine and nearby countries in Eastern Europe affected by the current heightened risk of terrorism in Europe?

Tags: schengen, europe, safety, ukraine, eastern-europe

Smartraveller's advice for [Ukraine](http://smartraveller.gov.au/Countries/europe/eastern/Pages/ukraine.aspx) mentions the terrorism threat for Europe:

> Terrorism
>
> There is an ongoing threat of terrorism in Europe. In the past,
>   terrorist attacks have occurred in a number of European cities.
>
> Terrorism is a threat throughout the world. See our Terrorist Threat
>   Worldwide bulletin.

Their page [Terrorist Threat Worldwide](http://smartraveller.gov.au/bulletins/pages/terrorist_threat.aspx) says

> Europe
>
> We assess that a heightened risk of terrorist attack exists in a
>   number of European countries due to the conflict in Syria and Iraq. In
>   the past decade, major terrorist attacks have occurred in a number of
>   European cities, such as Moscow, Oslo, Volgograd, Paris, Brussels,
>   Nice and Berlin. Targets have included public transport and transport
>   hubs as well as public places frequented by foreigners. European
>   security services are taking robust measures in response to the
>   current threat, particularly over the Christmas/New Year period. On 19
>   December 2016 a truck drove through a crowded evening Christmas market
>   in Berlin, causing a number of deaths and injuries. An attack in July
>   2016 in Germany, involving a radicalised person attacking train
>   commuters with an axe, underscores the ongoing risk of attacks by
>   individuals and small groups.

I'm aware of terrorist attacks affecting Western Europe (including Scandinavia), and Turkey, and possibly Russia, but I haven't heard about recent terrorist attacks affecting Eastern Europe (apart from the Ukraine conflict, which usually wouldn't be categorised as terrorism).

Is Ukraine generally regarded as affected by a heightened risk of terrorist attack? What about nearby Eastern European countries which are part of the Schengen area?

Comment: Your risk of being a victim of a terrorist attack anywhere in the West is about 10^6 less than the risk of your taxi crashing on the way from the airport...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, it is certainly not affected in any way.

Taking a look at the [Global Terrorism Database](https://www.start.umd.edu/gtd/search/Results.aspx?start_yearonly=2011&end_yearonly=2015&start_year=&start_month=&start_day=&end_year=&end_month=&end_day=&region=9&asmSelect0=&asmSelect1=&target=5&target=6&target=1&target=8&target=9&target=7&target=2&target=10&target=11&target=12&target=13&target=3&target=14&target=15&target=16&target=17&target=18&target=19&target=20&target=22&dtp2=some&success=no&casualties_type=b&casualties_max=) (arguably the most comprehensive listing of terrorist attacks) for incidents in Eastern Europe from 2011 to 2015, one can see that there have been a total of 1440 deaths from terrorist attacks. However 95% of those are either a part of the war in Donbass (1023 deaths) or part of the Islamic insurgency in the Russian Caucasus (390 deaths). This leaves only 27 deaths for other countries in the region, which is very much negligible as far as risks go.

The only significant terrorist attack (outside of Donbass and Caucasus) in recent times has happened in [Bulgaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Burgas_bus_bombing), where 7 Israeli tourists have been killed and 32 have been injured.

Comment: As I researched elsewhere, on average 90 people die in a year in the USA from a lightning strike per the [NOAA](http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/general/lib/lig1.pdf). Eastern Europe, by [some measures](http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/eastern-europe-population/) is about the same population or a little less so your chances of death by lightning strike is roughly thrice as much as being killed in a terrorist attack. Why are you not worried about that instead?

Comment: @chx 16 thousand people die in Russia every year from car crashes and 200 thousands are injured, just for the sake of comparison

Comment: Of course but everyone sort of knows car accidents are "frequent", I wanted to show something that everyone thinks are "rare".

Comment: @chx unlike the characters in https://xkcd.com/795/ I take reasonable precautions against lightning.